# How do I centered my menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing this theme: http://test.banglapdf.net/
to move my navigation menu right side of the page. I added 'container_class' => 'pull-right'
to my wordpress menu function. but when the theme's max-width is under 767 the menu is not looking good. I want to move it in the center of the page. I added .pull-right        {float:none;} to my responsive css file, but it is not working. what should I do? here is the css for my menu:

```
#main-nav {
    margin-top: 65px;
    float:right;
    background: #e1a221; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e1a221 0%, #f5c25a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e1a221), color-stop(100%,#f5c25a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e1a221 0%,#f5c25a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e1a221 0%,#f5c25a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e1a221 0%,#f5c25a 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e1a221 0%,#f5c25a 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e1a221', endColorstr='#f5c25a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
#main-nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.7em 1em;
    transition: background 0.8s ease;
}
#main-nav li:hover {
    background: #e2a529;
}
#main-nav li a {
    color: #522504;
    font: italic 1em "Marko One";
    box-sizing: border-box;;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #6a3107;
}

.current-menu-item, .current-page-item {
    background: #d79a1e;     
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
#main-nav {
    margin-top: 65px;
}
#main-nav li a {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#main-nav li {
    padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.pull-right {
    margin: 1em auto;
    float:none;
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: if you don't want to help, don't help. why give negative reputation? I don't see any problem with my question.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I understood your question and helped to get your reputation up +1... see if my answer helped any.

Comment: @AohorArsalan This site isn't here just to answer someone's question. It's also to help people with questions of their own. All relevant code should be posted on stackoverflow. What would a future person see when your links no longer work?

Comment: @MiniRagnarok yes, I'm sorry for that. I ll do it from the next time.

Comment: @AohorArsalan You can always edit this question if you want. Some people might even take the negative votes away. :)

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I edit my question. hope it is ok now. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your media queries you need to do this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#main-nav {
    margin: 1em auto;
    float:none !important;
}

#main-nav li {
    float:none;
    text-align:center;}

}
```

Somewhere around line 63 of your navigation.css make the media query look like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use some browser tools like Firebug for Firefox. Then you should check which rules are more important. In your case rule:
    .pull-right {
    float: right !important;
    }
from bootstrap.css has !important property, so your 'float:none' rule is overwritten.

On the other hand if you want to center your horizontal menu there is a very simple method - use:
    ul {text-align: center;}
    li {display: inline-block;}